# Cast a double from button title in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, option-type

I'm trying to retrieve the text of the selectedItem of a PopupButton, cast it as a double and do some math with it.

After reading and watching tutorials about optionals, I still can my head around what Xcode wants me to do, which is as follows:

```
let foo = Double((stundenPopup.selectedItem?.title)!)!*0.20;
```

(where the Popup button has been populated on viewDidLoad, and it doesn't change)
as I've read, it's not a good practice to be using ! operators here and there. If I understood correctly, the ! operator forces the unwrap. What I don't really get is why the ?, making the selected item optional and the second !

could somebody show me the light here?
It'd be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Converting a localized title to button is a strange thing in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For type casting, you cannot use optional values.
What you *can* do is the following:

```
guard let title = stundenPopup.selectedItem?.title else { /* title is nil */ return }
// now the title is not optional anymore
guard let double = Double(title) else { /* title is not a Double */ return }
// now you've successfully cast the title into a Double
let foo = double*0.2
```

Note that if `guard-let` statements fail, the rest of your function won't be called.
If you do want to continue your function after the statements, you could use `if-let`s:

```
if let title = stundenPopup.selectedItem?.title {
    // now the title is not optional anymore
    if let double = Double(title) {
        // now you've successfully cast the title into a Double
        let foo = double*0.2
    }
}
```

You could also define a default value, for when the title cannot be cast.
Here's a one-liner doing the same like the two examples above:

```
// if the title cannot be cast to Double, foo will be 0*0.2 which is still 0
let foo = (Double(stundenPopup.selectedItem?.title ?? "") ?? 0)*0.2
```

Comment: Thanks! I will read more about the guard function and I'll try that right away, then. Why is the ? there at the end of the selectedTitle?

Comment: Definitely go read more about optionals. You'll see what the `?` is for. (It tells that `selectedItem` is an optional, in this case.)

Comment: yes, that I know. What I don't get is why stundenPopup.selectedItem has to be optional

Comment: I'm not sure how you've declared `stundenPopup`, and of what type it is, but that doesn't really matter. The property of `stundenPopup`'s class `selectedItem` is declared as an optional.

Answer (score 2):

`let foo = Double((stundenPopup.selectedItem?.title)!)!*0.20;` can be read as follows :

`studentPopup` has a property called `selectedItem`. If `selectedItem`'s `title` property is not `nil`, access it. I am assuming `title` is an optional as well. So, the whole resulting expressing will be an optional. Unwrap the optional. But I want the whole result of this expression in a `Double`. So, use the `Double`s constructer. But uh, oh! `Double`'s constructor returns an optional type. So, unwrap the optional to yield a `Double` non-optional. Multiply with 0.20, assign it to `foo`. Done.

The reason why `selectedItem` *could* be an optional is that the person who designed the `stundenPopup`s type, with her best judgement,  thinks that there's a fair chance that `selectedItem` could have a value of `nil` at some point in its lifecycle.

This can be done using the concept of Optionals which is an explanation for another day, I suggest you read up about it.

Comment: This clarifies things a bit more, I'm reading indeed about it. This whole Obj-C to Swift leap it's been rough...

Comment: It's not that big of a leap, TBH. It's just a matter of getting used to, I guess. :)